# React: how do I set a state inside a get request?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a navbar and I want it to display the name of a user if they are signed in and I have this if statment:

```
var that= this;
this.state = {name: null, signedIn: false}
if (user){
      axios.get('https://apiendpoint/' + user.id)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response); 
          that.state = {name: response.data.firstName, signedIn: true}
          //this.setState({ showModal: false });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
```

The if statement is running, but the state variables don't seem to be getting set.  does `var that =this` not work to set state variables or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to use `that.setState({...});` rather than `this.state = {...}`